# NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException when exporting jasper to pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I created a `jasper` report and now I need to export that report to `pdf` format. This is my code for that.

```
        // compiles jrxml
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(reportName + ".jrxml");
        // fills compiled report with parameters and a connection
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName + ".jasper", parameters, connection);

        // to view the report
        //JasperViewer.viewReport(print, false);

        // export repor to pdf
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "fromXml.pdf");
```

When I view the report using `JasperViewer`, it works fine. But When I exporting the report into `pdf` format, it gives me the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
```

But I have put the iText jar into my libraries.

[image]

But one thing, I had another version of `iText` jar before. It gave me the same exception. I thought that there may be some issues with the version of it.(I followed a tutorial, so I added the same jar as they had used in the tutorial replacing the new jar I had used).

but still the problem remains. I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138623/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-itextpdf-text-documentexception) may be the issue now(the accepted answer of the question). But I do not know how to fix it. I removed the entire library and added it again with `iText` jar which had been used by the tutorial. But I had no luck.

Could you please help me to overcome this issue. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to upgrade your iText-2.1.7.jar file to latest version as earlier the package that was used by jar is `com.lowagie...`

See the change list [here](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/50) which says it has changed the package name.

Comment: now I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAWriter` exception

Comment: Yes because you dont have that class in any of the jar that you have showed in the classpath screen shot.

Comment: but it should come under `itextpdf.jar`. isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right. But you are using old version of the jar file. You should upgrade it as the package that you are looking for is in latest version i.e. 5.X. You wont find com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.class in your itextpdf-2.1.7.jar

Comment: thanks. found it here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118163/itextpdf-library-cant-find-the-class-com-itextpdf-text-pdf-pdfawriter